# Changing routes depending on user available in firebase database

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I am using signInWithGoogle to login and at the same time checking if the user already exists in the database. If not, user info is being added to the database.

Now I want to navigate to the `survey` page for new users and `profile` page to existing users. For a new user, the user info gets added to the database but is also navigate to `profile` page. I want the new user to navigate to `survey` page.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

export class LoginComponent {

  users: FirebaseListObservable<User[]>;

  constructor(
  private db: AngularFireDatabase,
  public afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
  private router: Router
  ) {
      this.users = this.db.list('/users') as FirebaseListObservable<User[]>;
    }

    signInWithGoogle() {
      this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider())
        .then((data) => {
          // Checking if the email exists in the database
          this.users.subscribe(users => {

            let exists = users.some(function(el) {
              return el.email === data.user.email;
            });

          // If email does not exists in the database i.e. New user
          if(!exists) {
            this.router.navigate(['/survey']);
            this.users.push({
              email: data.user.email
          })
          return false;
        }
        else {
          // If user already exists
          this.router.navigate(['/profile']);
          return false;
        }
      })

    })
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: you can make use of router resolve and check if the user existed or not if not navigate to survey else go to profile

Comment: @RahulSingh Thank you for your comment. Can you please show me how to implement router resolve in this case.

Comment: I have found the issue even with router resolve it wasnt working because when you are pushing to the firebase observable the whole subscribe is called again rendering the whole if case for the route useless . i am working on it will update you on the same

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is a full proff solution but here it is .
Making use of Local Storage here.

**LOGIC**

when we sign in we check if the data is present if not we show the normal signIn Component .

When the user clicks on SignIn we get the data and check if the data is present in the User Observable if not we redirect to the Survey component and before redirecting we save it to the browsers localstorage as email , then do what you survey thing there and then just when the component is destroyed the data is added to the observable which calls the resolve again and he is redirected to the profile page . without you needing to redirect.

I am not sure but this seems like a decent work around and before filling in the survey he cannot go the profile page too an added advantage .

**Component and Markup**

```
<button (click)="signInWithGoogle()">Sign in </button>

export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth) { }
  ngOnInit() {

  }
  signInWithGoogle() {
    this.afAuth.auth.signInWithRedirect(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
  }
```

**Router Resolve.**

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router} from "@angular/router";
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import {FirebaseListObservable} from "angularfire2/database/firebase_list_observable";
import {AngularFireDatabase} from "angularfire2/database/database";
import {AngularFireAuth} from "angularfire2/auth/auth";
import User = firebase.User;


@Injectable()
export class TestResolve implements Resolve<any> {

  users: FirebaseListObservable<User[]>;

  constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private db: AngularFireDatabase, private router: Router , private localStorage : localStorage) {
    this.users = this.db.list('/users') as FirebaseListObservable<User[]>;
  }

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any>|Promise<any>|any {
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe((data) => {
      if(data){
      this.users.subscribe(users => {
        let exists = users.some(function (el) {
          return el.email === data.email;
        });
        //If email does not exists in the database i.e. New user
        if (!exists) {
          this.localStorage.setItem("email",data.email);  
          this.router.navigate(['/survey']);
        }
        else {
          // If user already exists
          this.router.navigate(['/profile']);
        }
      });
      }
    });
  }

}
```

**Now in the Survey Component**

```
export class SurveyComponent implementsOnDestroy{
  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase , private localStorage : localStorage) { }
  ngOnDestroy(){

    this.db.list("/users").push({"email": this.localStorage.getItem("email")});
  }

}
```